How to Extend an Image Beyond Modal Boundaries in SwiftUI
I have a ProfileView that presents a modal called CoinPopUp when a button is tapped. The CoinPopUp contains an image that I want to extend above the modal's top boundary, creating an overlapping effect. However, I can't seem to get the image to extend outside the modal's boundaries.
In UIKit, this might have been achieved using the .clipsToBounds(false) method, which allows views to extend beyond their parent view's boundaries. However, I want to maintain the modal presentation style provided by SwiftUI, which includes the ability to minimize and extend to full screen if needed.
Here’s the relevant code:
ProfileView
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var user: User
    @State private var showPopUp = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // Top bar
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "trophy.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("4:45")
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        Button("291") {
                            showPopUp = true
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showPopUp) {
                            CoinPopUp(isPresented: $showPopUp)
                                .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                                .background(Color.clear)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                
                Spacer()
                
                // Profile Picture
                VStack {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .overlay(
                            Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        )
                    Text(user.name)
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: EditProfileView(user: user)) {
                            GreyButton(buttonText: "edit profile")
                        }
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: EditProfileView(user: user)) {
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.red)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 8)
                    
                    // About Section
                    HStack {
                        VStack {
                            Text("Followers")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            Text("5")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                        }
                        
                        VStack {
                            Text("Streak")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                            HStack {
                                Text("2")
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                Image(systemName: "flame.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 16)
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

CoinPopUp
import SwiftUI

struct CoinPopUp: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State private var selectedCoin: Int? = nil
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0
    
    let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), spacing: 10), count: 3)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Spacer().frame(height: 40)
                    Text("get coins")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
                        CoinOptionView(coins: 65, price: "$0.99", isSelected: selectedCoin == 65)
                            .onTapGesture { selectedCoin = 65 }
                        CoinOptionView(coins: 330, price: "$4.99", isSelected: selectedCoin == 330)
                            .onTapGesture { selectedCoin = 330 }
                        CoinOptionView(coins: 660, price: "$9.99", isSelected: selectedCoin == 660)
                            .onTapGesture { selectedCoin = 660 }
                        CoinOptionView(coins: 1320, price: "$19.99", isSelected: selectedCoin == 1320)
                            .onTapGesture { selectedCoin = 1320 }
                        CoinOptionView(coins: 3300, price: "$49.99", isSelected: selectedCoin == 3300)
                            .onTapGesture { selectedCoin = 3300 }
                        CoinOptionView(coins: 6600, price: "$99.99", isSelected: selectedCoin == 6600)
                            .onTapGesture { selectedCoin = 6600 }
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        // Implement coin purchase
                    }) {
                        Text("get 330 coins")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.pink)
                            .cornerRadius(25)
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        // Implement video ad playback
                    }) {
                        Text("tap for free coins")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .offset(y: offset)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            let newOffset = value.translation.height
                            offset = newOffset > 0 ? 0 : newOffset
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            if value.translation.height < -50 {
                                withAnimation {
                                    offset = -geometry.size.height + 100
                                }
                            } else {
                                withAnimation {
                                    offset = 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                
                // Image overlay to extend beyond the modal boundaries
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .overlay(
                            Image(systemName: "bubble.left.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.system(size: 24))
                        )
                        .font(.system(size: 60))
                        .offset(y: -geometry.size.height / 2.5)
                        .opacity(1 - min(1, offset * 0.02 ))
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // Ensure the view covers the screen
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5)) // Background dim effect
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) // Extend the view to cover the safe area
    }
}

struct CoinOptionView: View {
    let coins: Int
    let price: String
    let isSelected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(coins) coins")
                .font(.headline)
            Text(price)
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(isSelected ? Color.yellow : Color.gray)
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

Adjusting the offset values for the Image inside the CoinPopUp view.
Using .background(Color.clear) for the modal.
Ensuring the CoinPopUp view covers the entire screen using .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) and .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).
Despite these attempts, the image does not extend beyond the modal boundaries as intended.
How can I extend the image beyond the modal boundaries in SwiftUI to achieve the overlapping effect similar to this?
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

This post might help: Moving an image over a sheet SwiftUI
